# How to receive a file with an Aws Lambda (python)

Tags: python, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to figure out how to receive a file sent by a browser through an API call in Python.

The web client is allowed to send any types of files (let's say .txt, .docx, .xlsx, ...). I don't know if I should use binary or not.

The idea was to save the file after on S3. Now I know it's possible to use js libraries like Aws Amplify and generate a temporary url but i'm not too interested in that solution.

Any help appreciated, I've searched extensively a solution in Python but i can't find anything actually working !

My API is private and i'm using serverless to deploy.

```
files_post:
  handler: post/post.post
  events:
    - http:
        path: files
        method: post
        cors: true
        authorizer: 
          name: authorizer
          arn: ${cf:lCognito.CognitoUserPoolMyUserPool}
```

EDIT

I have a half solution that works for text files but doesn't for PDF, XLSX, or images, if someone had i'd be super happy

```
from cgi import parse_header, parse_multipart
from io import BytesIO
import json


def post(event, context):


    print event['queryStringParameters']['filename']
    c_type, c_data = parse_header(event['headers']['content-type'])
    c_data['boundary'] = bytes(c_data['boundary']).encode("utf-8")

    body_file = BytesIO(bytes(event['body']).encode("utf-8"))
    form_data = parse_multipart(body_file, c_data)

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    object = s3.Object('storage', event['queryStringParameters']['filename'])
    object.put(Body=form_data['upload'][0])
```

Comment: I tried this on a zip file but it ends up with a corrupted zip file in the bucket

Comment: check your zipping process, s3 is reliable, so only 2 locations where you can have a problem : either the file is not well zipped, or it's baddly transmitted

Comment: I am posting it with multipart/form-data, i am able to get the other form fields but the the file itself even though it gets updated when i download it i can no longer open it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a very similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537939/posting-image-using-form-data-via-api-gateway-to-lambda-function-results-in-inva) (and answered in the comments).

The short answer is that, to avoid CORS and to prevent file corruption, you need to:

1. use the AWS SDK to create an empty object in S3
2. return a pre-signed URL of that object to the front-end
3. PUT the file to that pre-signed URL

AWS actually maintains a [very good example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html) of implementing this scenario in Go.

In Python, a simple implementation would be something like:

```
import boto3
import os
import csv

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Upload the empty file to S3
s3.put_object(Bucket='foobucket', Key='somekey', Body='')

# Generate a pre-signed URL for the empty file
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'foobucket',
        'Key': 'somekey'
    }
)
```

You'll likely need to use `io.BytesIO` to byte stream your file in Python buffer, but prepare to write custom logic using specific Python libraries to properly stream the upload to the buffer.

Once your file is streamed to the buffer, just use the `Client.put_object` method:

```
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key, Body=buffer, ContentType='csv')
```

Remember to change tour ContentType to suit your needs (this example uses CSV).

Answer (score -1):

You are using API Gateway so your lambda event will map to something like this (from [Amazon Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format)):

```
{
    "resource": "Resource path",
    "path": "Path parameter",
    "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
    "headers": {String containing incoming request headers}
    "multiValueHeaders": {List of strings containing incoming request headers}
    "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {List of query string parameters}
    "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
    "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
    "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
    "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
    "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"
}
```

You can pass the file as a base64 value in the body and decode it in your lambda function. Take the following Python snippet

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = json.loads(event['body'])
    # Let's say we user a regular <input type='file' name='uploaded_file'/>
    encoded_file = data['uploaded_file']
    decoded_file = base64.decodestring(encoded_file)
    # now save it to S3
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i'm getting an error : No JSON object could be decoded: ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/post/post2.py", line 16, in post
data = json.loads(event['body'])